# How to make the "finals tree table", or what is it called?

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash, graphic

I'm working with some friends on a small private mini MMORPG game server, and we want to make a PvP event (players VS player) fights, and post the live results on the website as a tree.

I don't know what is it called, I tried every keyword combination on google and this is what I finaly came up with (2 pictures at the bottom).

I need the name of the two types of the trees, what is called so I can do more googling about it.

I also need to know if there is any PHP/HTML/JS or FLASH, Scripts or API or something that can help me accomplish this. I have no problem coding it from PHP/MySQL side, but it looks very hard to render and print on client side, because the tree can get really big if we get alot of players. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: cool graphic but start coding and if you encounter problems come back and ask. you know the drill.

Comment: @tradyblix these are not mine, I just need help to get started, i really have no idea where to start from

Comment: I think this question may be too broad and basically looks like a `canihaztehcodez` question which I'm sorry to say is offtopic here. Also tagging your question 5 languages doesn't really help attracting the best people to your question.

Comment: it doesn't matter if it's yours or for a friend but your question is too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a complete full binary tree I think.

[Here](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs3114/Spring10/Notes/T03a.BinaryTreeTheorems.pdf) you can find some mathematical info to binary-trees.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just googled it, and found alot of js APIs that can draw this very easy.